# Google CloudSQL unable to connect to Informatica behind proxy

Tags: google-app-engine, proxy, google-cloud-sql, informatica

I am trying to connect to CloudSQL DB from Informatica server which is inside a corporate proxy. I have got the Public IP of the server and added to authorized networks.

But unable to connect to server still and tried CIDR notation to add whole all IP's *.*.*.0/24.

Is there anyway in CloudSQL to get connections which are getting refused, so that it can be added to Authorized networks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you assign an public IP to your instance? This is necessary to be able to connect over the internet.

Can you create a new GCE VM to connect?

1. create VM with ubuntu image
2. run `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`
3. whitelist the VM's IP address in Cloud SQL
4. use the mysql client on VM to connect

To answer your question, "Is there anyway in Cloud SQL to get connections which are getting refused, so that it can be added to Authorized networks."

You can whitelist everything with "0.0.0.0/0" and "::/0" (IPv6).

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to see a log of the IP addresses of rejected connections. The IP address you should whitelist is usually what you see at [ip4.me](http://ip4.me/).

If whitelisting is the problem the error message should be "Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'". If you get a different error message you may be connecting to the wrong IP address, may not have an IP address assigned to your instance, or might have a corporate firewall stopping outbound MySQL connections (port 3306).